# Laravel Sentry and check user without login

Tags: authentication, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

It is possible to check user by credentials without login for:

- exits user
- password is correct
- is not banned
- is activated
- ...

As I can see, I must write a lot of code for this. Maybe exists any easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

Check the user is valid without `logging` in with `Auth` (Native):

```php
$credentials = array('email' => 'xx', 'password' => 'xx', 'deleted_at' => null);
if(Auth::attempt($credentials, false, false)) {
    // Exists and password is correct and not banned
}
```

This requires you to keep the `deleted_at` field in your table to [soft deleting](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting) technique (By disabling or enabling a user temporarily).

If you are using a different field to make a user `inactive/active` then pass that field instead of `deleted_at`, for example, you may use a field `active` with value `1` to indicate an active user and `0` for an inactive user, in this case pass `active => 1` to check the `active` field has value `1` as the third item in the `credentials` array.